# "Auto-Confirmation: Automatically Saying Yes" but how?

Tags: saving, compile, confirmation

i have

```
(defun insert-buffername ()
 (interactive)
 (compile (concat "lua " (buffer-file-name))))

 (global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-e") #'insert-buffername)
```

but when i use this key binding it always asks me "Save file: (y, n, !, ...)" question
which i would prefer not to see every time. I can not adopt the code in
https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/YesOrNoP to my case.
Need help

Answer (score 2):

Try customizing (or binding) `compilation-ask-about-save` to `nil`. `C-h v` tells you:

> `compilation-ask-about-save` is a variable defined in `compile.el`.
>
> Its value is `t`
>
> Documentation:
>
> Non-`nil` means `M-x compile` asks which buffers to save before compiling.
>
> ***Otherwise, it saves all modified buffers without asking.***
>
> You can customize this variable.

If you want to just bind it in your command, then do this:

```lisp
(defun insert-buffername ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((compilation-ask-about-save  nil))
   (compile (concat "lua " (buffer-file-name)))))
```

Comment: It works thanks, is there a way to skip the question: "A compilation process is running; Kill it? "(y or n)"

Comment: For that it looks like you would have to bind function `yes-or-no-p` to a function that just returns `t`, around the call to `compile`. E.g. (`(cl-flet ((yes-or-no-p (x) t)) ...)`)